# Folder structure for modular development with PHP and vuejs (or angular)

Tags: php, vuejs2, single-page-application, directory-structure

Essentially, I'm looking to have a PHP development workflow that needs to be modular, but using a Single Page Application technology.

I understand it is recommended to separate the back-end from the front-end. Develop them separately. But is there a way to group all related code into one module (or folder), meaning all backend code with its own views presentation inside the same folder?

It's like MVC, but the "V" contains fragments of vuejs (or angular) files, which extends from a master file somewhere in your project.

**For example**

Assume we are building a modular CMS, where you can upload "plugins" (really, PHP modules), extending the CMS' functionality:

```
-project[root-folder]
----core[folder] # contains all infrastracture code, api routes, master view file, magic, etc.
----modules[folder] # uploadable modules goes here
--------User[folder] # sample module; follows the MVC pattern
------------Controllers[folder] # contains files, e.g. UserController.php
------------Models[folder] # contains User.php
------------views[folder] # where vue components is housed
----------------users/index.php # contains vue code
----------------users/create.php # etc...
----------------users/js/user.js
----------------users/css/user.css
--------Blog[folder] # another module
----index.php # the master view or just the bootstrap file
----gulpfile.js
```

Then inside the core/ folder, there is a master layout that binds all views together.

Will a folder structure like this be viable?

Obvious problem there is you can't use .vue files (as that would mean, every time you upload a new module, you need to run gulp or re-compile).

Hoping for your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question will strike a lot of folk as bizarre and twisted. That's the reaction I got when [I asked it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310833/why-does-everyone-put-controllers-in-one-folder-and-views-in-another) in the context of .net mvc. I'm with you 100%.

I'm too new to js frontend development (and too ignorant of PHP) to have much advice. It's going to be tricky. Ajax calls to PHP code will need to go to paths below the src directory. But then you want to stop your frontend resources being served from these same paths. Both PHP and gulp will want to use file paths for urls, but at least for Gulp [this can be controlled](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/wiki/Clarifying-injected-paths).

I'll follow this with interest. My ambition is to keep in the same folder things you're likely to want to delete together, and for those things to be able to call each other with short, relative paths. The ideal would be to be able to specify the module route independently of the path on disk, and to have this route work for both frontend bundled resources and services. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question whilst searching for an approach for exactly the same problem. I'm building a "platform" rather than an application with a plugin system along the lines of Wordpress. I have the additional issue of the platform itself being a 'multitenancy' environment, too - so any plugins cannot interfere with the core "Dashboard" that holds these things together.

So; posting for a few reasons, two years on...

1. Did you get anywhere and would you care to share any thoughts?
2. I came across a quite extensive article for PHP Phalcon that has certainly given me a few ideas. Sharing incase it helps you/others:

https://blog.antsand.com/singlepost/index/5619/How-to-integrate-php-(Phalcon)-and-Vue.js-components

There's a line buried in the series that says "As a rule of thumb. Structure your code, based on the application and NOT on the programming language and frameworks." I'm not sure how wise or not this is, but it certainly gave me something to crack on with.

So right now, I have a module folder a bit like:

```
/mymodule
   /Controller
   /Model/
   /Template
      thing.vue
   /Assets
      /js
      /css
   MyModule.php
```

- Assets are handled via a framework route (i.e, /assets/{path:.*} )
- Templates are handled via the (PHP) module install script to make sure webpack knows where they live.

Still at proof-of-concept stage but rightly or wrongly, it seems to work well enough!